# Group Values together that are true

Tags: mysql

So let's say I have a table like this called animals the animals are a BIT for the value:

```
id   dogs  cats  birds lions 
1     0     1     0      0 
2     1     1     0      0 
3     0     1     0      1
4     0     0     0      1
```

I want to group the animals together that have a bit value of 1

Desired Output:

```
cats
dogs,cats
cats,lions
lions
```

I thought of using `GROUP_CONCAT` to put them together but didn't know how to only select true ones. Just an Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is not useful for this, it's used for concatenating a column across rows in a group, not concatenating columns within the same row.

You can use `CONCAT_WS()` to concatenate values within the same row, with a given delimiter (`','` in this case). It will only concatenate non-null values, so you want to replace true values with the column name, and false values with `NULL`.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 
        IF(dogs, 'dogs', NULL), 
        IF(cats, 'cats', NULL), 
        IF(birds, 'birds', NULL), 
        IF(lions, 'lions', NULL)) AS animals
FROM yourtable
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8QG75ZYVsgHM5RHRrNcpQP/1)

Comment: My value for the animals are a BIT while its an INT in the demo

Comment: It doesn't, change the demo from INTEGER to BIT and it gives an error

Comment: Just have to get rid of the quotes when inserting them.

Comment: Your table already has the data inserted, so that error was irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: DB Fiddle has a really crappy text-to-ddl function.

Comment: I tried the solution for some reason it only gives me the first result it gets and no more.

Comment: You used my solution exactly, or did you add more to it? Add your complete query to the question.